# First send by socket the size of the file I want to send

Tags: c, sockets, int, send, sizeof

I want to send a file to **program2**, but first I want to send the size of that file.
i have this in **program1**:

```
FILE *script;
int j;
int size;
char* codigo;
if (argc > 1){
  for (j = 1; j < argc; j++){
    if ((script = fopen(argv[j], "r")) == NULL){
        perror(argv[j]);
    }else{
        fseek(script, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(script); 
        fseek(script, 0, SEEK_SET); 
        codigo = malloc(sizeof(char)*(size +1));
            if(codigo) { 
            fread(codigo, sizeof(char), size, script);
                codigo[size] = '\0';
            }
            struct addrinfo hints;
                struct addrinfo *serverInfo;

                memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
                hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
                hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

                getaddrinfo(ip, puerto, &hints, &serverInfo);


                int serverSocket;
                serverSocket = socket(serverInfo->ai_family, serverInfo->ai_socktype, serverInfo->ai_protocol);

                connect(serverSocket, serverInfo->ai_addr, serverInfo->ai_addrlen);
                freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);  

                printf("Conectado al servidor\n");
                send(serverSocket, codigo, strlen(codigo) + 1, 0);
                close(serverSocket);
    }
    fclose(script);
    free(codigo);
    free(ip);
    free(puerto);
  }
}
```

Here in **program1** I'm sending the content of a script to **program2**. In **program2** I have:

```
#define PACKAGESIZE 100
```

I define that for `recv` the package, but this packagesize can be variable, so I need to **program1** send the size of the package i will send after that.
in **program2** when I have the size, then I can recive the package and print it.

Comment: How do you want to send it?  It's your protocol to define.

Comment: I want to send the size of the file. I think is IPV4 i u re asking me that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a fixed-sized integer for the file size, so both parties know how many bytes to exchange for the file size.  `send()` the size first, then `send()` the data as needed.  On the other side, `recv()` the size first, then `recv()` the data as needed.

For example (error handling omitted for brevity, DON'T ignore error handling!):

```
FILE *script;
int j, k, read;
uint32_t size, size2;
char codigo[1024];
if (argc > 1)
{
    for (j = 1; j < argc; j++)
    {
        script = fopen(argv[j], "rb");
        if (script == NULL)
        {
            perror(argv[j]);
            continue;
        }

        fseek(script, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(script); 
        fseek(script, 0, SEEK_SET);

        struct addrinfo hints;
        struct addrinfo *serverInfo, *server;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

        getaddrinfo(ip, puerto, &hints, &serverInfo);

        int serverSocket = -1;

        for(server = serverInfo; server != NULL; server = server->ai_next)
        {
            serverSocket = socket(server->ai_family, server->ai_socktype, server->ai_protocol);
            if (serverSocket != -1)
            {
                if (connect(serverSocket, server->ai_addr, server->ai_addrlen) == 0)
                    break;
                close(serverSocket);
                serverSocket = -1;
            }
        }

        freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);  

        if (serverSocket != -1)
        {
            printf("Conectado al servidor\n");

            size2 = htonl(size);
            send(serverSocket, (char*)&size2, sizeof(size2), 0);

            for(k = 0; k < size;)
            {
                read = fread(codigo, sizeof(char), 1024, script);
                if (read < 1) break;
                send(serverSocket, codigo, read, 0);
                k += read;
            }

            close(serverSocket);
        }

        fclose(script);
    }
}
```

```
FILE *script;
int j, read;
uint32_t size;
char codigo[1024];

int clientSocket = accept(...);
script = fopen(..., "wb");

recv(clientSocket, (char*)&size, sizeof(size), 0);
size = ntohl(size);

for(j = 0; j < size;)
{
    read = recv(clientSocket, codigo, 1024, 0);
    if (read < 1) break;
    fwrite(codigo, sizeof(char), read, script);
    j += read;
}

fclose(script);
close(clientSocket);
```

Comment: ok, I implemented this. Sends the size (very long), then i think it sends the data but it doesnt print it.

Comment: `htonl()` converts a number from *host byte order* to *network byte order*, and then `ntohl()` converts it back. You should always send integers in network byte order for compatibility across different machines and platforms. Yes, you *CAN* use a fixed 1024 byte array. Look at what the code is actually doing. It readis the file in 1024 byte chunks, sending whatever bytes it actually reads, until it reaches the end of the file. The file size is actually variable length. You do not have to (nor should you) read the entire file into memory before sending it. Same on the receiving end.